# A special trick needs a special name

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

What do we call the process $(-1)^n$ that we use to alternate $+$ and $-$? Do Mathematicians call it something like "the alternator"?

Comment: Maybe the alternate operator ^^

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean for when $n$ is a real integer, so it is equal to either $1$ or $-1$. We have the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) but this is different. I am not sure if there is a specific name for this, more when considering a series of these terms we talk about their value and absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that we refer to anything containing $(-1)^n$ as *alternatingly signed*; this passes also on objects characterized by the presence of $(-1)^n$ (see, for instance, [*alternating series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series)), or by its elements being limited to $\{-1,0,1\}$ (e.g. [*alternating sign matrices*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_sign_matrix)).
Also, when multiplying by $(-1)^n$, we very often refer to it by expressions like "*the alternating factor*".

Unless you're looking for some other, more specific use, I would say that "*alternating (something)*" is a pretty standard expression.